Running the MakeADFun becomes very slow for large matrices
Using the TMB library for R I am currently implementing an SPDE model which requires me to construct some sparse matrices within the objective function. After this I use SimplicialLDLT on these matrices for computing the log-determinant and solving linear systems.
Compiling the template is relatively fast, but I face long runtimes when calling the MakeADFun-function. For smoothness parameter beta=1, running the function takes typically only a couple of seconds. However, for beta>1 the MakeADFun-function suddenly takes several minutes to run.
Here is a slightly stripped down version of the objective function I use. Most of the operations performed are similar to what we can find in the density and R_inla namespaces.
#include <TMB.hpp>
template<class Type>
struct spde_new_t{
  int n_s;
  vector<Type> C_diag;
  SparseMatrix<Type> G;
  spde_new_t(SEXP x){  /* x = List passed from R */
  n_s =     CppAD::Integer(asVector<Type>(getListElement(x,"n_s"))[0]);  
  C_diag = asVector<Type>(getListElement(x,"C_diag"));
  G = tmbutils::asSparseMatrix<Type>(getListElement(x,"G")); 
}
};

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
//   using namespace R_inla;
  using namespace density;
  using namespace Eigen;

  // SET UP DATA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  DATA_SCALAR(log_nu);
  DATA_VECTOR(y);
  DATA_STRUCT(spde,spde_new_t);
  DATA_SPARSE_MATRIX(A);  //Matrix for interpolating points witin triangles

  // SET UP PARAMETERS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  PARAMETER(log_kappa2);
  PARAMETER(log_sigma2);
  PARAMETER(log_sigmae2);

  Type nu = exp(log_nu); 
  Type beta = (nu + Type(1.0)) / Type(2.0);
  Type kappa2 = exp(log_kappa2);
  Type sigma2 = exp(log_sigma2);
  Type sigmae2 = exp(log_sigmae2);
  Type taue = Type(1.0) / sigmae2; 
  Type scale_factor = kappa2;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //  Building the Q matrix

  // Constructing the C, Ci and I matrices
  SparseMatrix<Type> C(spde.n_s, spde.n_s);
  SparseMatrix<Type> Ci(spde.n_s, spde.n_s);
  SparseMatrix<Type> I(spde.n_s, spde.n_s);
  // Initialize matrices to zero
  C.setZero();
  Ci.setZero();
  I.setZero();
  // Fill the diagonal
  for(int i =0; i<spde.n_s; ++i){
    C.coeffRef(i,i) = spde.C_diag(i);
    Ci.coeffRef(i,i) = 1 / spde.C_diag(i);
    I.coeffRef(i,i) = 1;
  }

  // Constructing the G and L matrices
  SparseMatrix<Type> G = spde.G;
  SparseMatrix<Type> L = G + kappa2 * C;
  
  L = L / scale_factor;
  SparseMatrix<Type> CiL = Ci * L; 

  // Constructing the Pl-matrix
  SparseMatrix<Type> Pl;
  SparseMatrix<Type> Pr;
  Type Pl_scaling;
  Pl = L; 
  Pr = I;
  if (beta > Type(1.0)) { 
    for (int i = 1; i < beta; i++) { 
      Pl = Pl * CiL; 
    }
  }
  Pl_scaling = pow(scale_factor, beta);
  Pl = Pl * Pl_scaling;

  // Constructing the Q matrix
  Type pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
  Type twobeta = Type(2.0) * beta;
  Type noise_scale = (exp(lgamma(twobeta)) / exp(lgamma(twobeta - Type(1.0)))) * Type(4.0) * pi * pow(kappa2, twobeta - Type(1.0)); 
  SparseMatrix<Type> Ci_noise_scale = Ci / noise_scale;
  SparseMatrix<Type> Q = Pl.transpose() * Ci_noise_scale * Pl;

  // Compute the NLL
  Type nll = 0.0;

  // The contribution from the Q matrix
  Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Type>> Pl_solver;
  Pl_solver.compute(Pl);
  Type logdetPl = Pl_solver.vectorD().array().log().sum();  
  nll += logdetPl;

  // Computing Q_post
  SparseMatrix<Type> APr = A * Pr;
  SparseMatrix<Type> Q_post = Q + taue * APr.transpose() * APr;

  // Cholesky decomposition of Q_post
  Eigen::SimplicialLDLT< Eigen::SparseMatrix<Type> > Q_post_solver(Q_post);

  // The log determinant of Q_post
  Type logdetQ_post = Q_post_solver.vectorD().array().log().sum();

  // In practice even more computations are done here, but not needed for the minimal reproducible example

  // Return the negative log likelihood
  return -nll;
}

The matrices C, G and L are very sparse, but also very large (typically with size approximately 5000x5000). The generated Pl and Q matrices will be slightly more dense (depending on the number of for-loop-iterations determined by beta), but still relatively sparse. Note that the procedure of iteratively multiplying Pl with CiL is similar to how the precision matrix in the GMRF-class in density.hpp is convolved with it self "order" times. I need to build the Pl this way to control the smoothness of the GRF related to the GMRF with precision matrix Q.
How can I make the code (in particular the MakeADFun) faster? Is there anything that can be improved with the way the function is written?
I have not enabled any optimizations for C++. Is this something which can significantly impact the runtime?

"I have not enabled any optimizations for C++. Is this something which can significantly impact the runtime?": Yes! Benchmarking C or C++ without compiler optimizations is pointless.
